# Unity3d wheelcollider falling through terrain

Tags: unity, 3d, terrain

I have created simple project with 3D car and terrain. I have added 4 Wheel Colliders on model wheels. But when I run project wheels falling through terrain.

Before run:
[image]

After run:
[image]

I am sure that at start wheel colliders above the terrain and not intersect it. Configuration is:
[image]

In what problem is? I have tried a lot of different things but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried starting with the car levitating above the ground? For performance purpose it's possible that the collisions are not computed on first frame, and that could be why your car is in the ground. (I don't write this as an answer as I'm not 100% sure that will help you, but tell me if it helps).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but situation is the same.

Comment: Ho.. hum.. in your post you don't mention Rigidbody... On which part your rigidbody is located?

Comment: On Car top object.

Comment: Could this possibly be your problem? Your car doesnt seem to fall through.I have no experience with wheels, but many libraries I know usually only care for there task, thus a WheelCollider might tell you that you collided, but will do nothing to solve it? Better ckeck the Documentation...

Comment: Bit of a bodge, but try just extending the bodys collider down to include the wheels. This should keep the car above ground. Not sure if what the effect will be accross rough terrain though...

I just had a closer inspection of the prefs, have you tried increasing the radius of the wheel colliders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do "not rotate" the WheelCollider components. WheelColliders are implemented as ray casted down, you can see the direction of the ray on selecting the same in the editor. To get more accuracy try tweaking [Physics.minPenetrationForPenalty](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-minPenetrationForPenalty.html) and [Time.fixedTimeStep](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html).

Edit:
Noticed the rotation in your inspector window.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, on a model imported from Blender. Blender uses a different axis than Unity, so the imported model had an x-rotation of -90 degrees and the wheel collider ray-casts forwards, instead of downwards.

To fix it, in Blender:

> In object mode, set the X rotation of your model to -90. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and apply rotation, X rotation appears to be 0 now in Blender, set it to 90 and save/export it. You'll see that it will appear both correct and at 0 rotations now.
>   **<sub>- [Unity Answers: Rotation when importing from Blender](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/319802/rotation-when-importing-from-blender.html)</sub>**